# Get incremental changes between Hive partitions

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

I have a nightly job that runs and computes some data in hive. It is partitioned by day.

Fields:
id bigint
rank bigint

Yesterday
output/dt=2013-10-31
Today
output/dt=2013-11-01

I am trying to figure out if there is a easy way to get incremental changes between today and yesterday

I was thinking about doing a left outer join but not sure what that looks like since its the same table

This is what it might looks like when there are different tables

SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON (a.id=b.id AND a.dt='2013-11-01' and b.dt='2-13-10-31' ) WHERE a.rank!=B.rank

But on the same table it is

SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN a
ON (a.id=a.id AND a.dt='2013-11-01' and a.dt='2-13-10-31' ) WHERE a.rank!=a.rank

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM A a LEFT OUTER JOIN A b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.dt='2013-11-01' AND b.dt='2013-10-31' AND <your-rank-conditions>;
```

**Efficiently, this would span 1 MapReduce job only.**

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out... Using Subqueries and Joins

select * from (select * from table where dt='2013-11-01') a 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select * from table where dt='2013-10-31') b 
on (a.id=b.id)
where a.rank!=b.rank or a.rank is null or b.rank is null

The above will give you the diff..

You can take the diff and figure out what you need to ADD/UPDATE/REMOVE

UPDATE If a.rank!=null and b.rank!=null i.e rank changed
DELETE IF a.rank=null and b.rank!=null i.e the user is no longer ranked
ADD if a.rank!=null and b.rank=null i.e this is a new user

Comment: Query is a champ and exactly to the point but would span **3 MapReduce jobs**. Also, I couldn't figure out why do we need FULL OUTER JOIN when LEFT OUTER JOIN can give us difference/incremental data.